# Deploy a VM via Ansible on ESXi Host

Tags: deployment, automation, ansible, vmware

i am trying to deploy a VM via Ansible on an ESXi Host.
They both know each other (i copied the SSH ID File, so we do not need to enter a password).
so, i used the following role in ansible:

```
- vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: emea-esx-s18t.mydomain.net
    username: myuser
    password: mypassword
    guest: newvm001
    state: powered_off
    vm_extra_config:
      vcpu.hotadd: yes
      mem.hotadd:  yes
      notes: This is a test VM
    vm_disk:
      disk1:
        size_gb: 10
        type: thin
        datastore: storage001
    vm_nic:
      nic1:
        type: vmxnet3
        network: VM Network
        network_type: standard
    vm_hardware:
      memory_mb: 4096
      num_cpus: 4
      osid: windows7Server64Guest
      scsi: paravirtual
    esxi:
      datacenter: MyDatacenter
      hostname: esx-s18t.mydomain.net
```

So while u use this role, i get the following output:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook -i Inventory vmware_deploy.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.20.22.5]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.20.22.5                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

This is the vmware_deploy.yml file:

```
---
- hosts: vmware
  remote_user: root
  roles:
   - vmware
```

The ESXi host is the 172.20.22.5 !

But when i take a look on the ESXi Host, nothing happend.. i dont know why? he said its okay but nothing changed or happend here?
Do you guys maybe know whats wrong here?

PS: I needed to make the domain, password, user and stuff looking different in this example thats why there is listed "myuser", "my...",...

Comment: Your output says that ansible just connected to 172.20.22.5 and gathered initial data (setup meta task). No user tasks were actually done. Please provide your vmware_deploy.yml listing to see what are you trying.

Comment: Okay no problem here it is:
`---
- hosts: vmware
  remote_user: root
  roles:
   - vmware
`
and the 172.20.22.5 is the ESXi Host.

Comment: Please edit the question with this additional information.

Comment: okay , i've done it it should be in the Question now, all informations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `./roles/vmware/tasks/main.yml` is in place.

Comment: Okay, that was my Mistake. Done File is now on the "task" folder but now i get a new error message:
`fatal: [172.20.22.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "pysphere module required"}`

do i need to download the module on the ESXi Host? or on my Ansible Server? I am running Ansilbe on an Ubuntu OS