# Ansible - pysphere module required

Tags: ansible

i am trying to install a VM via Ansible on an ESXi host. 
I am using the role and the playbook you can see here -> [Deploy a VM via Ansible on ESXi Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699074/deploy-a-vm-via-ansible-on-esxi-host)

But now i am getting an Error:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# ansible-playbook -i Inventory vmware_deploy.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.20.22.5]

TASK [vmware : vsphere_guest] **************************************************
fatal: [172.20.22.5]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "pysphere module required"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.20.22.5                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

so it seems to be that the module "pysphere" is not installed, so i tried the command "apt-get install pysphere" but he cant found any package named like this (yes the server got a working internet connection)!
so can you guys maybe help me how i could install it?
i hope my playbook works then .. :/

kind regards,
kgierman

EDIT:

```
root@ansible1:~/ansible# pip2 install pysphere
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysphere in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysphere-0.1.7-py2.7.egg

root@ansible1:~/ansible# pip3 install pysphere
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install python3-pip
```

so it seems to be that i got a pip2 version installed and not a pip3 version

Comment: Please show the playbook and task.

Answer (score 0):

If `apt-get install pysphere` it means that there is no deb package for this Python module available. Use `pip` instead:

```
pip install pysphere
```

As noted in the [documentation for the vsphere_guest module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html) that packages need to be installed on the Ansible control host:

> Requirements (on host that executes module)
>
> ```
>  python >= 2.6
>  pysphere
> ```

Comment: okay, i did exactly this but now i get the followung message back:
`root@ansible1:~/ansible# pip install pysphere

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysphere in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysphere-0.1.7-py2.7.egg`

this means the package is already installed, right? but why the package doesn't work then?

Comment: okay i edited my question , so you can see more clearly what the output says - it seems to be that i have installed a Python2.X version and not a Python 3 version , so this might be not the mistake :/ 
I hope you can still help me @ my problem